# ios8 Custom Keyboard: Why when I add UIImages does it not run on my device?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I have built a Custom Keyboard and it works fine in the simulator across the range of devices, but when I try to load on my iPad Mini, also running ios8, it gives the error

plugin ... keyboard interrupted

Or sometimes it gives a memory warning.

When I take the pictures out (Each Key is a picture) then it works. Is this a restriction? Am I not allowed to use UIImages. If so, why do they work with the simulator, but not an actual device?

Here is the code I was using to add the images:

```
        var myName : NSString = String(buttonTag) + ".png"
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: myName), forState: .Normal)
```

buttonTag is an int value and so I am converting it into a string in the process above. My keys are generated through code and so the above code was nested in a loop where buttonTag keeps increasing by 1 from 1 to 33 and my images are named 1.png, 2.png etc

Comment: Please add some code snippet so that we can help you to get the solution. I don't think there should be any issue with UIImage usage as I have used it in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

Apple mentions in their App Extension Programming Guide that memory limits for app extensions are significantly lower than limits imposed on foreground apps. Additionally some types of extensions may have lower limits than others.